# How can I use requestAnimationFrame for animating by changing css clases?

Tags: javascript, css

I have 4 different classes, let's say .go1, .go2, .go3 and .go4.
For example:

```
span
     transition: all .25s ease-in-out

span.go1
     transform: translate(44px, 39px);

span.go2
     transform: translate(60px, 71px);
```

I want to animate the span element by changing the classes, I can do this with setInterval, but I'm wondering if it can/should be done by using requestAnimationFrame and how to use it in this case.

Comment: Are you aware of transition events, such as [`ontransitionend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions#Detecting_the_completion_of_a_transition)?

Comment: No, not really. But I will look into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> Can/should be done by using requestAnimationFrame

No, `requestAnimationFrame` is not a good choice in this case.

rAF will try to update every screen vblank (it will try to update the next vblank when you use it like this) which will too fast for altering classes on an element. It will look very nasty... A transition will take x time to complete and calling rAF while this is happening makes no sense as it has to wait until the end of he transition.

Look into animation and keys with css3:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations

and as commented events connected to this (`transitionend` or `webkitTransitionEnd` for webkit) which allow you to trigger your next transition when event is triggered.